# Django REST Framework - "Must be Device instance" error when calling PUT from javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework

I'm getting an error when trying to update an object instance using PUT using the rest framework:
ValueError: Cannot assign "{'id': UUID('954...8b4')}": "DeviceConfig.device" must be a "Device" instance.

view defn:

```
class DeviceConfigViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #todo: secure
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset = DeviceConfig.objects.all().order_by('device')
    def get_queryset(self):
        device = self.get_renderer_context()["request"].query_params.get('device')
        if device:
            return DeviceConfig.objects.filter(device=Device(device=device))[0:]
        else:
            return self.queryset
    serializer_class = DeviceConfigSerializer
```

DeviceConfig model:

```
class DeviceConfig(models.Model):
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device,primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bpm = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=3, blank=True, null=True, default=0.5)
    duty = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=4, blank=True, null=True, default=0.022)
    ledState = models.IntegerField(
        default=255,
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(255), MinValueValidator(0)]
     )
    pressureMax = models.IntegerField( blank=True, null=True, default=70, validators=[MaxValueValidator(255), MinValueValidator(10)])
```

JS func FE side:

```
   function formSubmit(){
        var myForm = document.getElementById("config-form");
        var formObj = new FormData(myForm);
        var object = {};
        formObj.forEach(function(value, key){
            object[key] = value;
        });
        object["device"] = DEVICE_UUID;
        const putMethod = {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' // Indicates the content 
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(object) 
        }
        fetch("http://localhost:81/configs/"+DEVICE_UUID, putMethod);
    }
```

I've tried not sending the device ID from the front end but it gives me a 400 then
the ol' goog search didn't turn up much for me this time, but I'm not quite sure how to send a Device instance from the client side besides by it's pk
which is what I've tried

**EDIT - DeviceConfigSerializer**

```
class DeviceConfigSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    device = serializers.UUIDField(source='device.id')
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceConfig
        fields = ('device','bpm', 'duty','ledState','pressureMax')
```

Comment: Please add your `DeviceConfigSerializer` class

Comment: @JPG added in edit

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out. @JPG helped point in the right direction, it was the serializer - i was needlessly referencing device, which was screwing things up. I've removed it from the serializer and JS and all works well now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @JPG

Given the reference to the device ID was already in the url I was calling, there's no need to pass it in again. I'm still not quite sure how to interpret the error (insight appreciated) but my thoughts are it was attempting to assign a plain UUID where it needed a Device instance, which was not being handled in my serializer code as I thought it was.

Cheers

Comment: The thing is, when django serializer generates a field for you, it know the kind of field to generate and how to serializer/deserialize that field. However, when you make changes to the field, and it no longer matches, you have to tell the serializer how to deserialize.